# Are there robotic 'worms' that can burrow in soil and detect metals (e.g. gold), possibly via X-ray?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I looked it up didn't find anything. I was reading about mining and wonder if it's a technology that's used, as I didn't see any mention of it. I suppose the worms would have to be relatively large, maybe between large-dog-breed sized to automobile-sized because of the need for a sufficiently high-capacity battery, if not petroleum-powered.

Comment: This is a question that is going to need to wait quite some time since stackexchange is notorious for not being able to answer no. Anyway you looking for groundpenetrating radar? Sample drilling? Xrays dont work because youd need to have a reciever behind ground, which offcourse is on the other side of the globe most of the time. But yeah if its a mountain then you can in fact use cosmic radiation as the radiation source. This has been done to the great pyramid of giza for example.

Comment: [X-ray fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_fluorescence) will tell you the elemental analysis of a sample. It works in an epifluorescence mode and you do need to be in contact with the specimen.